# Provision to change server IP in Angular app in production

Tags: angular, angular8

I have created an Angular web app using Angular 8.
The Angular web app connects to a Java Jetty server though the endpoints of format 
http://ip-address-of-server:port/endpoint-name.
I had used environment.ts file to specify the IP address of the server.

Now, I have to provide the Java Jetty server and the Angular webapp to a client (Just the webapp and .war file, no source code to be given). Who would then install them in their private setup. Thus, the production IP addresses are not known beforehand.

Thus, How can i give provision to allow to edit the server ip address in Angular webapp in production?

Comment: You shouldn't have the server address anywhere. Just use URLs such as `/api/foo` instead of `http://ip:post/api/foo`, and the core will connect to the server where it comes from, whatever its IP or port is. Bonus: it will support https natively, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more maintainable solution would be Dockerize your application. You would provide the docker image and your client can simply spin up a container on the port he wants.

You just have to write the end points and everything would be serving up at localhost.

It's a one time effort to build a docker image, but will help to provide the fixes later instead of providing war files. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your environment setup like this:

```js
import * as deepmerge from 'deepmerge';

export const environment: EnvConfig = deepmerge<EnvConfig>(
  {
    apiEndpoint: 'http://ip-address-of-server:port/endpoint-name',
    // other stuff
  },
  (typeof INJECTED_CONFIG === 'undefined' ? {} : INJECTED_CONFIG),
);
```

and when you are serving app you can inject `INJECTED_CONFIG` variable into your index.html (on server side)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
...
<body>
  ...
  <!-- Injections -->
</body>
</html>
```

your server can replace `<!-- Injections -->` with

```html
<script>
var INJECTED_CONFIG = { apiEndpoint: 'http://0.0.0.0:port/endpoint-name', }
</script>
```

On server side you can read value for `apiEndpoint` from server environment.

Such application will replace all environment setup from provided `INJECTED_CONFIG` so you may want to reduce the scope of what you want to enable for replacment.

Answer (score 1):

In my project we have worked on something similar.
In the environment.ts file I refer to some variables that I previously configured in a config file.
You can probably let the client configure this file with the values ​​they need, or something else (in my case, it will be overwritten on runtime in my docker image).

HOW?

First your must declare typings file to set your global variable.

typings.d.ts

```
    declare var ENV_CONFIG: EnvConfig;

    interface EnvConfig {
        ENVIRONMENT: string;
        API_URL: string;
        CLIENT: string;
    }
```

environment.ts file

```
    export const environment = {
       appVersion: require('../../package.json').version,
       env: ENV_CONFIG.ENVIRONMENT,
       apiUrl: ENV_CONFIG.API_URL,
       client: ENV_CONFIG.CLIENT
    };
```

config.js file:

```
    let ENV_CONFIG = {
        ENVIRONMENT: 'production',
        API_URL: 'http://ip-address-of-server:port',
        CLIENT: 'yourClientName'
    };
```

Finally, you need declare your file into index.html:

```
  <script src="./your/config/file/path/config.js"></script>
```

After that, you can use your env properties as always.

`public API_URL = environment.apiUrl;`

Hope it helps!

Comment: I would try it out. Weather the config.js file be available for edit after i build the Angular app for prod ?

Comment: Exactly! My problem was that I needed to configure those values ​​after having done the angular build and it is the best way I found to solve it.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot a fundamental part and it is to add the file in the index.
I edit the comment explaining this

Answer (score 0):

If both the server application and client application are both on same env. then you can used - this.window.location.hostname to get the hostname and build the endpoint.

If you are maintaining the env. files, then in that case, you need to provide the interface to edit that or asked manually to change that ..
environments/environment.prod.ts

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Editing env files isn't an option, as I would be supplying the /dist folder contents to the client.